# Which layout/activity is referred to by the parent parameter in the getView method?

Tags: android

In the getView method in the custom adapter made:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

Which activity is referred to by the parent parameter?

Is it the xml layout to which the new inflated objects will be added? (The one that has this) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#4689C8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

or is it the java activity that contains the actual values of the list (as an array) and contains this:

```
final ListView listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope I made it clear and please tell me if it is not

Comment: It depends on where you're inflating this xml, e.g if you're inflating it in your activity using setContentView it will be layouted in the main container of this activity

Comment: share your adapter code

Comment: public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

Comment: I wrote the inflate() method in the getView method of the custom adapter I made. For the MainActivity that has the ArrayList of the actual content of the list, the setContentView has the xml I provided in the question. The list_item mentioned in the previous comment is the xml layout of the custom adapter and it has the layout that I want for the list (two text Views and an image)